# jQuery, Proper context for window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I am trying to load a web page in a new window on class="link" Below is what I have but it does not seem to work in IE 7-8

```
    $('.clicky').mousedown(function(){
        window.open("http://google.com");
    });​
```

Here is the complete context http://jsfiddle.net/Zw5c2/14/

Foolish me it was my pop up blocker. But I modified the script to open in the same window

```
        $('.link').mousedown(function() {
            window.location="http://google.com";
        });​
```

Comment: It works in Chrome fine...what is it not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: Did you check to see if your browser is blocking popups?  Your code may be correct but the browser prevents the window from opening.

Comment: It works for me in IE8.  The popup is blocked but if I temporary allow popups it opens the window fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is probably blocking popups. You can try to use the `.click()` event instead or add a "normal" anchor tag with the url as href.

Answer (score 0):

Works in IE6/7/8 for me, ran then on virtual boxes.

I believe your popups are indeed disabled.

check your [settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843016) if the browser doens't ask to allow popups.